"Schema https not found" Exception
I am trying to send data to ActiveMQ broker, the url I specified in code is https://XXXXXX.com, and I am getting run time exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Schema https not found

I tried below code
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url,username,password);
        try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()) {
             connection.start();
             Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
             Destination queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
            
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(jsonData);
            message.setStringProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 

            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            producer.send(queue,message);
         }
         catch(JMSException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }


The ActiveMQ Artemis Core JMS client doesn't support the https schema so the error you're seeing is expected. If you really need support for both HTTP and SSL then you can try something like this:
tcp://XXXXXX.com:443?sslEnabled=true;httpEnabled=true

See more details in the documentation.
